# How can you be certain that a controversial change made to your software really is best for users?

Tags: language-agnostic, gui, delphi

**Background:** we have recently made a significant change to the UI of our software.  All previous versions used a MDI interface (windows floating around inside a parent window.)  The new version uses a [docked interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394289/recommendations-for-a-docking-library-for-delphi-cbuilder) (windows snap next to each other, fill all available space, and can be tabbed on top of each other, and can be dragged out to another screen.)  We thought - and still think - this is a great improvement.  However, feedback from our alpha testers is wildly varying.  Some love it, some say they find it hard to use and want to use the old system.  Many of our users have been using the software for well over a decade and are very used to its old UI behaviour.

**Generic situation:** I'm sure other software houses have encountered similar problems, ie I think this is a widely applicable problem we will probably all encounter at some point: you make a change (especially a significant change) that you think will be greatly beneficial for the users of your software, and you don't receive universal acclaim.

- How can you be certain that your
  change really is better *for the user*,
  instead of just a change you happen
  to like?
- In my experience, change is usually
  liked more when it's voluntary or
  sought out, not forced.  How do you
  enthuse your users so that it is
  voluntary?  Should you even try?  How
  do you handle this situation?

*I have tagged this question 'delphi' because there is an interesting specific parallel: a decade or so ago the Delphi & C++Builder IDE (which we use!) changed from floating windows to a docked UI - exactly the same as us.  A small, very vocal group of people complained loudly and some still do to this day.  As far as I know, the majority think it was a great change. If there happen to be any Borland / Embarcadero staff reading who feel like chiming in with a historical tale, I'd love to hear your input!*

Comment: If the alpha testers can come up with valid complaints, listen. If it's just "I like the old better" it's probably not a real issue. Think of all the dozens of Facebook groups that have protested new FB features, and then a month later everyone loves them. Nobody still complains about the very existence of the news feed, but it caused a riot when it was introduced.

Comment: Delphi supports both docked and undocked interfaces, so maybe thats your solution.

Answer (score 5):

## usability testing

## *before* you make the change

You may have just spent a great deal of effort fixing a problem that did not exist!

Comment: Good point!  Luckily, we prototyped before implementation and it met with approval.  I've also seen lots of users use our software 'in the field'.  I'm pretty confident the way it was was not optimal.

Comment: @David so...you did usability testing with the old MDI interface, which identified some critical usability problems, and you determined that the solution to these problems was to change to a docked interface. Then you did usability testing with the docked interface and verified that the usability problems were indeed gone, and no significant new ones were created. Right?

Comment: Well, we are now testing with external users.  In-house, our testing makes it seem better.  Externally, it's mixed.  Of course, some new usability problems were created - they always will be... IMo they're acceptable so long as they are resolved or are less bad than the original problems, ie net improvement.  Ideally the new solution would be perfect.

Comment: @David: I'd be curious to know that usability problems MDI had that docked windows solved. Might be a good lesson for everyone in there...

Comment: @Stephen: I was trying to keep this question fairly generic so I won't add this to my question, but off the top of my head: window switching is hard (and they overlap so without manual arrangement data is obscured); the overlap requires manual alignment (Arrange All etc behave oddly - as a programmer I know it's based on the z-order, but as a user it's not clear); cannot be spread across multiple monitors; managing several windows at once (eg, different views of the same data) simply can't be done.  A docked and tabbed interface solves all those.

Comment: @David: excellent info, thank you. A video demo/tutorial showing how it solves the old problems might calm the waters and reassure the users

Answer (score 4):

**Testing**

In web development, [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) is by far the best way to answer those questions.

To your specific example, have you tried giving it to new users and, better still, then given them the old product for comparison? It's absolutely true that a change to the UI can cause hellish problems in the short-term for experienced users of the old product.

But if it's better for someone who hasn't used the product before then it will almost certainly become better for the old users too, given time. However, sometimes what seems like a great idea to developers isn't great to the average person.

Comment: I haven't heard of "A/B testing" as a phrase before; thanks for a link.  We are in fact running a testing day with new users tomorrow - it will be interesting to see their feedback!

Re better for old users over time: this is what we hope.  How do they know that, though, or how do we get them to be happy or satisfied with the change?  We like having happy customers :)

Comment: How hard would it be to give them the choice? Let's face it, a good number of WinXP Early Adopters switched back to 2K mode for a while

Comment: @pdr: sure, although it has to be worth the coding/QA/Doc time.  But if we think it's worth leaving the old one in, why do we think it's worth having the new one?  How or why should we be confident / not confident?  And if we are confident, how should we present it to users?

Comment: Confidence: Testing again. Presentation: Gently. Understand their pain. Explain to them why you're sure it's better for them. And if they don't agree, but you're absolutely sure, go with it and I'll bet they're not complaining in three months. If they are, you've probably made a mistake.

Comment: I'm not certain Binary comparative techniques will be useful in this case.  This technique can be useful to test small incremental change but in this case it would not provide much more than what he already know... some like it, some don't.  Usability testing here would be MUCH more appropriate

Comment: @Newtopian, how is anything I've suggested not about usability testing?

Comment: though you can use A/B testing as part of a usability test plan it is far from providing enough information by itself.  I actually have never seen A/B type test outside simple things like testing which color or size would best influence conversion rates.

Comment: @Newtopian - That's not the fault of A/B Testing, it's the fault of data recording. If the only KPI being recorded is conversion rates, that's the only one which you can compare in A/B Testing. If you monitor different things (simple examples: how many hits to help buttons, how many times people go back and correct a form) then you have a usability test.

Comment: @pdr: you missed my point, A/B testing is used to compare two distinct states.  no matter how many things you record if you ahve too many changes it becomes next to impossible to determine which changes are affecting your measurements variables.  The OP is talking about a complete UI overhaul.  Comparing the old with the new will very predictably lead to a majority of existing users not liking the new one and newer uses probably liking the new one instead.  I can mount a big testing framework but using A/B testing will still lead me to this conclusion...

Comment: ... further more the amount of changes are very large and measuring each possible changes in comparison with reach-other at a scale at which the measurement points will yield useful data will grow very fast (think factorial combinatory math).  A more holistic approach for example testing the time to complete a typical task in correlation with specific measurement points in the application will yield results that are much more useful with a lot less resources. Please read the wikipedia page on usability testing and tell me how A/B testing can be defined as such by itself.

Comment: @Newtopian - I think you'll find I only recommended A/B Testing as an answer to the more generic final question and in fact specifically referring to web pages. I then went on to talk about David's specific problem and never suggested A/B Testing for that.

Comment: @pdr - I guess I got carried away with the wikipedia reference here ! I apologize for the perceived harshness my comments could instil.  I agree with you that A/B testing is a useful tool to have for asserting changes and their impacts on a user's perceptions of the system.  Though I still think that in the particular case exposed here it would be insufficient as a final strategy, it would nonetheless be a useful tool to help manage changes when done incrementally through out the development.  I guess it was I who missed your point.  Thank you for keeping this discussion civilized :-).

Answer (score 3):

**Change is scary**

Keep this in mind when you show long time users that you are changing everything about the way you interact with the application. While I personally think that your proposed change will be friendlier to new users, the long time users *depend* on the way things are.  It took them a long time to become proficient, and they've all come up with little systems to make using the application more useful to them.

When you change everything "for the user's good" those users now have to relearn everything they already knew.  It's a real disincentive.  Think about your gut reaction when you saw Microsoft Office 2007 (or 2010) for the first time.  "Where is everything?"

**Change is an interruption, then it's done**

People will adapt, however you have the user interface organized.  To that end, consider the following questions:

- *How long does it take to adjust to the new way of doing things?*  For example, did you completely rearrange the menu structure while changing the way windows are organized?  That can be a catastrophic no-no.  Limit yourself to only one *major* UI change at a time.
- *Do new users learn the interface faster with the change or without it?*  You need to demonstrate some tangible benefit to the users.  Use an A/B test with new users to focus your results.  If you can reduce training costs with the UI change, you'll start to win over the pointy haired bosses.
- *Can existing users still do their job?*  The more a user has to do something, the quicker they will adapt.  The problem is that if the change is too different and the user can't find the critical functions they need to do their job, you've failed them.

**Can change be good?**

Absolutely, yes.  The question you have to answer is *why* is this change good?  Are you saving the user steps?  Are you reducing the amount of time twiddling with the screen and not doing work?

The next alpha test you do, apply the following:

- Have the users perform a set of tasks on the old interface.  Use *screen capture* to get a better idea of just how the user has found to make the app useful to them.  Also, time them.
- Have the users perform the *same* set of tasks on the new interface.  Time them, and use *screen capture* to get a better idea of just where they are stumbling.
- Once you've observed what they are doing, train them to bring their knowledge of the UI up to where yours is.
- Now, tell them you are doing a speed drill.  Have them do the same set of tasks as before on the new interface, but as quickly as they can.  Give them some sort of incentive.  The incentive doesn't have to be anything grand.  It can be something as simple as cookies for the winner.
- After all this, *now* ask them about their opinions.

What you are trying to do is educate the users how the change is really and truly better.

Comment: Btw, "Limit yourself to only one major UI change at a time" is good advice, I think.  This is the only major UI change in this version: the main menu is the same, shortcut menus are the same, menu items are in the same positions (for muscle memory), shortcuts are the same, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Thou Shalt Not Surprise Users**

A lot of users got used to your software and gained productivity. A major change of UI will be disaster to those who can already blind-type or blind-click inside your software. To them, how you layout the windows is irrelevant to their daily work. All they want is getting work done (faster). So if you slow them down, they will hate you.

**Some like new stuff**

Geek, developers and casual users usually like new stuff. Exchanging a mouse for a trackpad is fun to them. So this type of user welcome new interface and new themes.

**Change or not**

It really depends whether you want to sacrifice a group of your users for another.

**Solution ?**

*Option*. Allow your users to have an option. The option to use the new wonderfully dock-interface, or old efficient MDI interface.

Comment: Thanks ohho.  Having an option is something we've considered.  To me, this has drawbacks: it's easy to add an option instead of making a choice, and then eventually your software has a proliferation of options.  That leads to more combinations: more bugs.  It's also more code to maintain, or to re-implement.  Is it really the best solution?  I guess I'm thinking, 'If you're so uncertain about feature X you go through all this to let the user use feature X-1, why have it?'

Comment: Many usability experts also believe that options are at best a cop out for actually making a decision.  Not all change will be _initially_ popular, but that doesn't mean it wasn't good.

Comment: @David M: you may consider maintain _only 2_ versions, the latest version, plus a previous version. New features are only added to the new version. The old version receives bug fixes. Eventually, more users will migrate for the features (so you get revenue). And you still take care of the existing users.

Answer (score 1):

There's not necessarily going to be a universally accepted approval of the change.  Some people might find it better, and others will hate it.  You just have to live with the fact that you're going to annoy some users and perhaps chase some customers away.  Its about using your judgement - deciding what will help the most people, while limiting the annoyance to others, and most importantly, improving your overall sales.

Also **dont just assume those users complaining about the change dont have legitimate reasons for doing so**.  Particularly if you made the change 'just because', which you see a lot of in this industry.  If people are complaining about your switching from MDI to a docked interface, it may be because they cant as easily access the information they want to.  Make sure you sit down with them and actually watch how they use the software.  Developers and users use software differently.  And users may have different hardware.  That docked interface may look wonderful on your dual 24 inch 1080p wide-screen LCD monitors, but may be painful on a 17 inch 4:3 monitor, for example.  Or the previous arrangement allowed them to minimize mouse movements, but with the new system they're fast developing carpal tunnel syndrome.  Or before two items they need could be aligned right next to each other to be seen at a glance, whereas now it requires a head movement.

Answer (score 1):

User acceptance is the key. If the users don't like the change, you should not go for it. They are the ones who decide, not you. Just think about how many users the Microsoft Office engineers pissed when they decided to make major changes to the menus, layouts, etc. Did they think that the change was for good? Certainly. Did they test them on enough or the right users? It seems that not.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point? Is your goal to make the application more appealing to new users? Sometimes you have to move in that direction to grow your product and risk losing existing users. The usability may not improve, but it may "look" newer which gives the impression the product has the latest and greatest. You may have an older user base, so don't assume they have the latest and greatest hardware or operating system. I notice a lot of corporate laptops (stickers) on the train that are still on Windows XP.